# How to disable postlink in cakephp using jquery?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

This is my Postlink tag:

```
<?php 
echo $this -> Form -> postLink(__('Update'), array(
                                'controller'=>'users','action' => 'update', 'admin'=>false),array('class' => 'uiBtn uiBtnBlue','id'=>'up','title' => 'user update'),
 __('Are you sure you want update User?')); ?>
```

This is my code to disable button:

```
$(function(){
     $('.ui-button-text').live('click',function(){
            var buttonName=$(this).text();
                 if(buttonName == 'Continue'){
                    $('#image-b-loading').attr('disabled','disabled');

   }
  });
});
</script>
```

above disable attr not working ??

Answer (score 1):

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is removed in jQuery 1.9, meaning you'll need to use the newer form of event delegation, which is [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

You would use it like such:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-button-text', function(){
    $('#image-b-loading').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

you'll note also we use `.prop()` and not `.attr()`. This is because the above is a property.

Also, `document` is a static element, it should be replaced with the closest parent element.